# Python mocking table schema

Tags: python, pytest

I have a simple python function that needs tested that looks like this:

```
# Get columns from BigQuery table
def get_schema_for_table(bq_client, source, schema, table):
    bq_table = bq_client.get_table(f'{source}.{schema}.{table}')
    return bq_table.schema
```

However, to test this, I don't want to test with a real table - I would like to create a Mock schema within my test (and a mock client too).

My test currently looks like this:

```
def test_get_schema_for_table(mocker):
    mock_client = mocker.patch('google.cloud.bigquery.Client', autospec=True)
    Table.schema = MagicMock(return_value=[
        SchemaField('column_1', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None),
        SchemaField('column_2', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None),
        SchemaField('column_3', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None)
    ])
    source = 'project'
    schema_name = 'dataset'
    table_name = 'existing_table'
    expected_schema = [SchemaField('column_1', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None), SchemaField('column_2', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None), SchemaField('column_3', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None)]
    returned_schema = get_schema_for_table(mock_client,source,schema_name,table_name)    
    print(returned_schema)
    assert returned_schema == expected_schema
```

However, when I print `returned_schema`, I get the following: `<MagicMock name='Client.get_table().schema' id='4591155568'>`.

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you set the value for `Table.schema` but you have already mocked `google.cloud.bigquery.Client`. When you access any value on your mock_client you just get another magic mock - but you can define what these mocks should return.

So you need to set the expected return value on your `mock_client` directly.

Replace you code with this and it should work (although the test might seem a little pointless at that point)

```
    mock_client.get_table("project.dataset.existing_table").schema = [
        SchemaField('column_1', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None),
        SchemaField('column_2', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None),
        SchemaField('column_3', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None)
    ]
```

Although if you want to test more properties I'd suggest the following approach:

```
    mock_table = mock_client.get_table("project.dataset.existing_table")
    mock_table.schema = [
        SchemaField('column_1', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None),
        SchemaField('column_2', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None),
        SchemaField('column_3', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, (), None)
    ]
    # you can mock additional properties of your table
```

Comment: I still get the same ```<MagicMock name='Client.get_table().schema' id='4748341456'>``` printed when I print the ```returned_schema``` after making the above change

Comment: Oh - my bad - wait I'll edit the answer - you have a mock for 'Client' but that mock doesn't magically register when you set something on Table.